# Rate of convergence for expected absolute difference of indicators of sets when there is a l2 rate

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I have a sequence (f_n) of continuous functions with values in $[0,1]$, a random variable $X$, and a function $f$ such that $E[(f_n(X) - f(X))^2] < n^{-r}$, with $r > 0$. The p.d.f. of $f(X)$ is continuous.

I wonder if there exist $M > 0$ and $r' > 0$ such that, for all $\delta \in [0, 1]$,

$E[|I(f_n(X) < \delta) - I(f(X) < \delta)|] < M n^{-r'}$.

Comment: I guess I figured it out: $P[|I(X_n < \delta) - I(X < \delta)| = 1] = P(|I(X_n < \delta) - I(X < \delta)|, X \not\in [\delta - \epsilon, \delta + \epsilon]] + P(|I(X_n < \delta) - I(X < \delta)|, X \in [\delta - \epsilon, \delta + \epsilon]]$. Then $P(|I(X_n < \delta) - I(X < \delta)|, X \not\in [\delta - \epsilon, \delta + \epsilon]] \leq P( |X - X_n| > \epsilon) < E|X_n -X|^2 / \epsilon^2$. Besides $P(|I(X_n < \delta) - I(X < \delta)|, X \in [\delta - \epsilon, \delta + \epsilon]] < \sup_{x \in [0,1]} f(x)  2  \epsilon$. Optimizing w.r.t $\epsilon$ yields the claim, with $r' = r/3$.